# Find the level of a node in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to find the level of a node using xslt.

Logic

```
ol/li/ul/li ---> <p type="list_bullet_2>

ol/li/  ---> list_number
     ul/li/  ---> list_bullet_2
          ul/li/ ---> list_bullet_3
               ol/li/ ---> list_number_4
                    ul/li  ---> list_bullet_5
```

This is also only for li when there is no child p.

How can I do using xslt. I am using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
<xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:copy>
            <p type="{concat('list', if(local-name(..) = 'ol') then 'number' else 'bullet', if(ancestor::li) then concat('_',count(ancestor::li)+1) else '')}"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ3919

Answer (score 1):

To find the nesting level of particular node, you can use:

```
count(ancestor::*)
```

To find `li` element with no `p` child, you can use:

```
li[not(p)]
```

either in *select* or in *xsl:template match*.